# visual studio 2015 professional toolbox not viewed

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed visual studio 2015 trial version from microsoft site. When i open the new project(Blank App (Android)) the tool box contains the following text only.
"There is no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox."
Please find the attachment for your reference.

Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkvIq.png)

Comment: Try openning in safe mode. Run  `devenv.exe /safemode`